# Getting the first item out of a For loop

Tags: php, joomla, for-loop

I am writing my own Joomla component (MVC), its based heavily on the newsflash module, because I want to display the latest 5 content items in a sliding tabbed interface, all the hard work is done, but I am having real difficult getting content out of the for loop.

Here is the code I have so far
default.php

```
<ul id="handles" class="tabs">
    <?php for ($i = 0, $n = count($list); $i < $n; $i ++) :
            modSankeSlideHelper::getTabs($list[$i]);
     endfor; ?>                
<li class="end"></li>
</ul>
```

helper.php

```
function getTabs(&$item)
{
    global $mainframe;

    $item->created     = $item->created;

    list($year, $month, $day) = split("-", $item->created);
    $tabdate = date('d\/m\/y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));

    require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_sankeslide', '_tab'));
}
```

_tab.php

```
<li><a href="#tab"><span><?php echo 'Shout ' . $tabdate; ?></span><b></b></a></li>
```

The first item needs to have  different value and a class item added to the a: item, so I need to be able to identify which is the first item and do something during that loop.

I tried to use if $i = 0 else statement in the default.php, but it resulted in a page timeout for some reason!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said, you tried `if $i = 0`, the [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/operators.comparison) in PHP is `==`, with your if you have an endless loop, because in each iteration you assign 0 to $i, and it never reaches $n, you should do inside your loop:

```
if ($i == 0){
  // First Item here...

}else{
  // Other Items...

}
```

Comment: Would using the old 0 == $i trick cause an interpreter error so that this old C trick would make a useful paradigm for PHP as well?

Comment: I have awarded you the right answer even though tvanfossen had a good idea. But you pointed out the main error the dreaded double equals. I new that, and cant believe I missed it!! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

I think @CMS is correct.

You might also want to think about handling the first item outside the loop and letting the loop handle the rest of the items.  This way you don't have to make the check on each pass through the loop.

Comment: tvanfosson, good idea but I need to use that same list of items later on in the same page, so I cannot unset anything although i did have a go at copying it and unsetting, but that screwed up the mktime!! Anyway many thanks,

Comment: I just meant to have the loop index start at 1 rather than at 0.  Do the first item before the loop starts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a plain `for` loop, I'd recommend just acting on the 1st item and then looping through the rest as [tvanfosson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12950/tvanfosson) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238376/getting-the-first-item-out-of-a-for-loop#238392).  It's slightly faster and potentially easier to read...

```
doSomethingWithFirst($list[0]);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($list); $i++) {
    doSomethingWithTheRest($list[$i]);
}
```

I tend to use `foreach` over `for` to loop over arrays, in which case, I would use a "firstDone" var, like so:

```
$bFirstTime = true;
foreach($list as $item) {
    if ($bFirstTime) {
        doSomethingWithFirst($item);
        $bFirstTime = false;
    } else {
        doSomethingWithTheRest($item);
    }
}
```